# How can I declare only once a button to all activities (including List Activities)?

Tags: android, button, static, android-activity

I want to develop an application that has 4 buttons top and 4 buttons bottom in all activities. The problem is that I don't want to define button's handlers in all activities (because it is simpler to make modifications in only 1 place).

One solution I thought was: Do a Main Menu that extends Activity then extend all activities from Main Menu. However, I want to use Lists that extend from ListActivity.

Is there a way to declare and define handlers only once and use those buttons in all activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved that issue implementing a singleton class.

Imagine that an application had 4 fixed buttons. You write 4 methods for those buttons in the singleton class and then call them from every Activity you write. Isn't the perfect solution, however it grants you a single space where you can change the handlers and spread those modifications automatically by all activities.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to refactor a `ListActivity` into an `Activity` that has a `ListView`. If you do this, you can follow your "Main Menu" plan.

Comment: And that is the easiest way or there is some solution better? If I define the buttons on a xml for the Main Menu they will extend for the others activities aswell? Thanks for the fast answer by the way :)

Comment: You will probably need to do some manual inflation, either of your button bars or the rest of the content so that you can merge the two in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: That solution would work with 2 activities. However, I will need about 10 Activities with those buttons. I was searching and yes, ListActivity seems easy to refactor. Besides, I will need also to convert a MapActivity to Activity (since I want to use Google Maps) and that seems harder (since probably Google API will not find that amusing).

Comment: You may also consider using a menu instead.

Comment: A context menu? Yes I could consider that, however this is a requirement for that app :)